# Stop reading standard input in Java

Tags: java

The following code will give me what I want which is the type of data entered (int, double, or string) however, when I run the code it is as if it expects another input before it will execute. I hope I'm on the right path.

[image]

or

```
Enter some stuff: 43
3
You have entered an integer: 43
```

It will not run until I enter another character in this case the 3 below 43.

Thanks for looking.

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // variables

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input;

        // Prompt user for stuff

        System.out.print ("Enter some stuff: ");

        // input stuff
        input = in.next();

        //determine and read type echo to use
        if (in.hasNextInt())
        {
        System.out.print ("You have entered an integer: "+ input);
        }
        else if (in.hasNextDouble())
        {
        System.out.print ("You have entered a double: "+ input);
        }
        else if (in.hasNextLine())
        {
        System.out.print ("You have entered a string: "+ input);
        }



    }
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: JavaScript is not Java. Also, please include the output text in your question rather than a screenshot.

Comment: You are reading a token, then checking if there is another token that has a specific type - and after checking that, displaying the first token. Call `in.nextInt()` after checking... remove `in.next();` and `input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `try` and `catch` in order to found the right data type. Don't use multiple inputs otherwise you will get the error that you got, just use `in.next()` once and then handle the value as below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    // Prompt user for stuff

    System.out.print ("Enter some stuff: ");

    // input stuff
    input = in.next();

    //determine and read type echo to use
    try {
        int v = Integer.parseInt(input);
        System.out.print ("You have entered an integer: " + input);
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe1) {
        try {
            double v = Double.parseDouble(input);
            System.out.print ("You have entered a double: " + input);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe2) {
            System.out.print ("You have entered a string: " + input);
        }
    }
}
```

Output 1:

```
Enter some stuff: 7
You have entered an integer: 7
```

Output 2:

```
Enter some stuff: 3.0
You have entered a double: 3.0
```

Output 3:

```
Enter some stuff: sfsdfasd
You have entered a string: sfsdfasd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing it incorrectly. If you want to know the type of the data you entered, why would you read it first? You are first reading and storing it in `input` variable and determining the type of the next entered input. So, the message is also wrong. I've altered your code to get desired output

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    // variables

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input;

    // Prompt user for stuff

    System.out.print ("Enter some stuff: ");

    // input stuff
    // input = in.next();

    //determine and read type echo to use
    if (in.hasNextInt())
    {
    System.out.println ("You have entered an integer: "+ in.nextInt());
    }
    else if (in.hasNextDouble())
    {
    System.out.println ("You have entered a double: "+ in.nextDouble());
    }
    else if (in.hasNextLine())
    {
    System.out.println ("You have entered a string: "+ in.nextLine());
    }

}
```